# Animation for Android application startup

Tags: android, animation

I'm new to Android programming so want know if we can add a custom animation built in other animation creating tools like Macromedia Flash and all, to Android as the startup animation. To be more specific the application should launch with that animation. There are ways to create some in Android itself. But with more specific application I can create more effectively. Same for Buttons too, that if I can add custom buttons in Photoshop and add it to Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to convert your photoshop or flash files to android xml files.  You can try Codly.io. But I suggest you start doing it the native way,  through xml and Java.